# PHP: find out the primary key of the just-inserted row data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find out the id value which is the primary key of the table. In order to do so, I implemented a code like this.

```
public function addNewPost($userName, $content) {

    // insert post information into the data.
    $query = "INSERT INTO posts(uploader, content, uploaded_at) VALUES('$userName', '$content', NOW())";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), $query);
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($this->db->connect());

    if ($result) {

        // get the row data with the found primary key
        $query_get_row_data = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result_row_data = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), $query_get_row_data);

        return mysql_fetch_array($result_row_data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here I tried to get the id by running thhe `$id = mysqli_insert_id($this->db->connect());` command, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a connection variable not a function call. A second call to `connect()` is returning a new connection.

```
$connection = $this->db->connect();
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

Or if you keep a variable in the db class which makes sense:

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->db->connection, $query);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($this->db->connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the connection

```
public function addNewPost($userName, $content) {

    // insert post information into the data.
    $query = "INSERT INTO posts(uploader, content, uploaded_at) VALUES('$userName', '$content', NOW())";
    $con = $this->db->connect();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    if ($result) {

        // get the row data with the found primary key
        $query_get_row_data = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result_row_data = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), $query_get_row_data);

        return mysql_fetch_array($result_row_data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```